# Recursive REGEX with outermost bracket

Tags: regex, recursion

I have a string `[Gr. butan, without, [see but,] literally, around, on the outside.]` which represents etymology for a word "about"

Using a REGEX, recursive, how do I capture the internal text `Gr. butan, without, [see but,] literally, around, on the outside.`  ???

I have see other examples with parentheses that I tried, but it didn't work...

`$pattern = "/\[([^\]]+)]/";`

`preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);`

Obviously, this is one REGEX with a nested `[see but,]` and I would want it to work generically for at least one level of recursion.  It would be nice to capture the nested values, if possible.

Comment: Without the recursion, you can get the internal substring with `^\[(.+)]$`

Comment: Try `(?<=\[).+(?=\])`

Comment: or maybe you just need `substr($about, 1, -1);`

Comment: Use [`\[((?:[^][]++|(?R))*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/lO09pp/1)

Comment: You could also use [`\[\K.+(?=])`](https://regex101.com/r/7NJ8dr/1) without recursion

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture values inside nested brackets using recursions in PCRE. You need a workaround:

```
$str = "[Gr. butan, without, [see but,] [literally, [around]], on the outside.]";
$values = [];

// Verify each opening bracket has a closing
while(preg_match('/\[(?:[^][\\\\]*+|\\\\.|(?R))*]/', $str)):
// Store and replace values inside brackets
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(?!)|\[([^][\\\\]*(\\\\.[^][\\\\]*)*)]~', function($matches) use (&$values) {
    return "\\[".($values[] = $matches[1])."\\]";
}, $str);
endwhile;

print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => see but,
    [1] => around
    [2] => literally, \[around\]
    [3] => Gr. butan, without, \[see but,\] \[literally, \[around\]\], on the outside.
)
```